# Oracle APEX cannot set the session of a page item set via javascript

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In my javascript I am setting page item:

```
apex.item("P2_TAB").setValue($tabVal);
apex.server.process ( "SAVE_HIDDEN_VALUE_IN_SESSION_STATE", 
 {
      x01: $tabVal,
      pageItems: "P2_TAB"
  }, 
  {dataType: 'text'} );
```

The value of `P2_TAB` gets set but when I view session, P2_TAB does not show up. In Affected Elements I selected Item(s) and P2_TAB. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The documented example includes the hash prefix on "#P2_TAB" https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/aeapi/apex-server-namespace.html#GUID-BB4896FA-3546-4DBB-8FB3-E28717E90B87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here:

```
apex.item('P2_TAB').setValue($tabVal);
apex.server.process('DUMMY', {pageItems: '#P2_TAB'}, {dataType: 'text'});
```

If you do this frequently in your application, maybe is useful to create a function like

```
setValueInSession(itemName, itemValue)
```